# What does `this` refer to inside an AngularJS provider?

Tags: angularjs, this

What does `this` refer to inside an AngularJS provider?

> And the value it is assigned is based exclusively on the object that
>   invokes the this Function.
>   Source: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Based on above I think `this` references the object which invokes the function that `this` is inside.

**So in below example example...**

```
sth.provider('Cat', function CatProvider() {

    var resourceName = 'user';

    this.resourceName = function(value) {
        if (value === undefined) {
            return resourceName;
        }
        resourceName = value;
        return this;
    };

    this.$get = function($q, $http, $rootScope) {
    ...
    }

}
```

**...does `this` refer to `sth` or to `.provider`?**

I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to the `CatProvider` function. If you check the AngularJS Documentation for **[`angular.Module.provider()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#provider)**, then you'll see this description:

> Register a provider function with the $injector. **Provider functions
>   are constructor functions, whose instances** are responsible for
>   "providing" a factory for a service.

Since provider functions are **constructors**, then that only suggests that the function itself is instantiated and thus, **`this`**, refers to the instance of the instantiated `CatProvider` function.

Comment: So in the question's example, it should be possible to call `resourceName()` outside of the Provider with the code `CatProvider.resourceName()` - is that correct?

Comment: No, since `resourceName()` is an instance method and not a static method, therefore you need to instantiate CatProvider first and then access `resourceName()` in that instance.

Comment: However, doing so is definitely an Angular Way of doing things, since providers are predominantly singletons by nature. Just the `angular.Module.provider` instantiate it for you. If you do have methods that you want to share across the `run` phase of the application then you should put those methods inside the `this.$$get`, to be shared as a factory.

Answer (score 1):

In EcmaScript 5, which you are using, this refers to the function it is used within ...

```
function Jim() {
    // this is the Jim function
    var self = this;
    function Fred() {
        // this is the Fred function
        this.name='fred'; // I have added a name property to the Fred function
        // I can access Jim here by referencing self
        self.name='jim'; // I have added a name property to the Jim function
    }
}
```

this is how we do it in EcmaScript 5.

In EcmaScript 6 it is all changed and the above no longer applies. You will meet EcmaScript 6 in a browser near you very soon :)